# Buffer overflow from print statement in fortran

Tags: fortran, buffer-overflow, abaqus

I'm trying to edit an old Abaqus user subroutine for my own project. I am attempting to debug some segmentation faults using print statements (on a university computer and the code requires input from abaqus so using a proper debugger is not possible), however, when I use a print statement it aborts with a message saying: `*** buffer overflow detected ***: *path* terminated`.

The first few (5 maybe?) times I ran it this morning it actually worked and printed as expected, but then stopped. I've tried using `call flush(6)` to clear out the buffer but that didn't help. Should I be using a different unit? Or clearing the buffer a different way? Or something else entirely?

I'm new to Fortran and only kind of experienced with programming in general so please any advice on this issue would be appreciated!

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
SUBROUTINE UMAT(STRESS,STATEV,DDSDDE,SSE,SPD,SCD,
    1  RPL,DDSDDT,DRPLDE,DRPLDT,STRAN,DSTRAN,TIME,DTIME,
    2  TEMP,DTEMP,PREDEF,DPRED,CMNAME,NDI,NSHR,NTENS,
    3  NSTATV,PROPS,NPROPS,COORDS,DROT,PNEWDT,CELENT,
    4  DFGRD0,DFGRD1,NOEL,NPT,KSPT,KINC)

     INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'
     CHARACTER*80 CMNAME

     DIMENSION STRESS(NTENS),STATEV(NSTATV),
    1  DDSDDE(NTENS,NTENS),DDSDDT(NTENS),DRPLDE(NTENS),
    2  STRAN(NTENS),DSTRAN(NTENS),TIME(2),PREDEF(1),DPRED(1),
    3  PROPS(NPROPS),COORDS(3),DROT(3,3),
    4  DFGRD0(3,3),DFGRD1(3,3)
    
     dt = DTIME
       
     print *, "TEMP", TEMP
```

Note: I believe this is using fortran 90 and intel 2020

Comment: You include statement is not syntactically correct. Are you sure you are showing the real exact code?

Comment: Buffer overflow can mean many different things. Please read the tag description at [tag:buffer-overflow]. Pften it means yyou are accessing wrong memory.

Comment: Thank you for catching that. The original code had several blank lines that I removed and must have deleted too far. I think I understand the basics of what a buffer overflow means - I just don't know why it is happening here or how to fix it.

Comment: maybe try some compiler options to check the correctness of memory access and argument passing? (I don't know the latest options for "intel 2020", but maybe "man ifort" (?) shows info...)

Comment: What happens if you try printing `temp` in the calling subroutine?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the calling subroutine. The output from this subroutine is to abort with a buffer overflow.

Comment: I mean the subroutine which calls `umat(...,temp,...)`. If you put a `print` call just before the call to `umat` what happens? (If this subroutine is hard to find, try compiling with stacktrace enabled, which should point you in the right direction)

Comment: @veryreverie UMAT is called by proprietary code in Abaqus, UMAT is a user-supplied callback.

Comment: Oh, fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using `write(6, *) "TEMP: ", TEMP` does what I need without the buffer overflow which is good enough for me

Comment: That is highly suspicious. It hints that you have some incorrect memory access somewhere and the results of your computation are suspect.

Comment: @VladimirF Hmm that's good to know. In your experience, is that likely to affect the results I get from Abaqus? My priority right now is to get the minor edits I need for my project working. The code is pretty complex and not well documented. Tracking the original author's memory issues down is probably beyond both my skills and the time I am willing to spend on this if it won't affect the results. Or are there other reasons I should try to go after them?

Comment: No one can say, the effects could be completely random-like. But contamination of the model results is certainly possible.